# Is it possible to instance the inheritance of a generic base class as type of the parentclass?

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I'm stuck here, this is the current structure of my code:

```
public abstract class AbstractInterface { }

public abstract class paramBase { }

public class paramUser : paramBase { }

public class paramServer : paramBase { }


public abstract class BaseInterface<Tparam> : AbstractInterface where Tparam : paramBase
{
    //do something
}

public class UserInterface : BaseInterface<paramUser>
{
    //do Something
}

public class ServerInterface : BaseInterface<paramServer>
{
    //do something
}
```

Now I want to set a variable of another class to an specific Interface Type

```
public class A
{
    protected BaseInterface<paramBase> CurrentInterface;

    protected void Initialize()
    {
        CurrentInterface = new UserInterface();
        //This fails

        BaseInterface CurrentInterface_2 = new UserInterface();
        //Fails as well, because BaseInterface requires 1 type argument 
    } 
}
```

So my question is, if there is a way to even do so.
I want to generate new Interfaces like a ServerInterface or a ClientInterface and so on, which all inherit from the BaseInterface. Every one of them takes different parameters on creation, which is why I transferred them to individual classes.

So what I don't want is

```
BaseInterface<paramUser> CurrentInterface = new UserInterface();
```

Which works, because I can't set the CurrentInterface to a ServerInterface (which takes paramServer) anymore.

If this is not doable at all I would be happy for any suggestion on how to handle this problem.

Comment: The first attempt would work if `BaseInterface` was defined as [covariant](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx), but to do that requires that the generic type only be used as outputs, so it depends on what methods/properties are defined on `BaseInterface`

Comment: The second attempt will not - there is no `BaseInterface` interface defined that does not take generic parameters, so you can't create a variable of type `BaseInterface`.

Comment: You could create a variable of type `AbstractInterface` though..

Comment: @stuartd I could do that, but then I can't refer to methods declared in my BaseInterface like ClientInterface.update();

Comment: @DStanley sadly I'm using it as Input only at the moment. I want the Interface to take Delegates when I create it, for such things like notifications if it is disposed. And the second one.. I found it in the internet and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If this is not doable at all I would be happy for any suggestion on how to handle this problem.

Neither one of your attempts will work.  The first will not work because `BaseInterface<Tparam>` is not covariant, and since you mention that it takes `TParam` objects as inputs in some methods or properties, it cannot be covariant.

The second will not work because there is not a non-generic `BaseInterface` interface defined.  You *could* define one that contains the non-generic properties and methods (or just use `AbstractInterface`).

Also think about it this way - suppose you had a variable that could hold either a `BaseInterface<paramUser>` or a `BaseInterface<paramServer>`, and that interface has a method that returned an object of the generic parameter type.  How would you know at compile time what the result type of the method would be?  It could be either a `paramUser` or a `paramServer`.  If the answer is "they both inherit from `paramBase` so I'll just treat it as that", then just make your base-interface non-generic and return a `paramBase`.